# Is the Iterable Object from the ServiceLoader oredered?

Tags: java, iterable, serviceloader

I have a pretty simple question, but i can't manage to find the correct answer.

So in my project i have an abstract class "JmjrstPlugin", from which some other plugins inherit. I'm using javas ServiceLoader to find all of the plugin classes like followed:

```
public static Iterable<JmjrstPlugin> getPlugins() {   
     return ServiceLoader.load(JmjrstPlugin.class);
}
```

To my question: Is the Iterable Object i recieve from this function oredered.
(The JmjrstPlugin implements the Comparable interface and has a working compareTo method).

PS: the project is currently in a state which makes it impossible for me to test it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javadoc of [`ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) says:

> The **only** requirement enforced by this facility is that provider classes must have a zero-argument constructor so that they can be instantiated during loading.

That means it doesn't care whether your implementation classes implement `Comparable`, or not.

Also, a `Set` is generally an unordered collection, unless explicitly specified otherwise. The javadoc doesn't specify, so it is unordered.

Answer (score 1):

As documented in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html):

> Each invocation of the iterator method returns an iterator that first yields all of the elements of the cache, in instantiation order